# Custom Layout is not being centered inside a listview using constraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, listview

I'm trying to center the items of my listview which are a custom view to the center of a constraint layout but they only show at the left side.

I tried setting the horizontal bias of both the constraint and the list view to 50 and to 100 but the listView still doesn't show the Items in the center or anywhere else other than at the start. I tried using `layout_centerhorizontal="true"` but that does not work either. Bare in mind that the `listview` is being inflated inside a `fragment` which is inside a `ViewPager`.

UPDATE:
I fixed it by wrapping the custom_item xml inside a linear layout which filled the entire screen horizontally and added horizontal center gravity to the item.

Here is my xml:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentConstraint_tutor_fragment_loged"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/tutorListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the custom_Item:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="323dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/tutor_entry_panel_phones_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tutorIcon_cell"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:tint="@color/BlueColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_tutor_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userLogin_nameTextV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/BlueColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/deleteIconPhones"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tutorIcon_cell"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteIconPhones"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just need the custom view inside the listview to be in the center of the constraint layout. here is a Screenshot of the current state:

https://ibb.co/88KVQvq

desired state will be with the custom_item in the middle and not in the beginning of the constraintLayout:

https://ibb.co/XbtWJkw

custom_item snapshot:

https://ibb.co/rkDXmGs

Blueprint view of the viewpager in which this fragment is contained (Im trying to get the custom_item centered inside the viewpager's fragment):

https://ibb.co/XVR02Kq

Comment: why you have given 
`android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: @APP making the constraint match its parent size, those are inside a parent constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a **custom_listView** then Do change in the `custom_layout.xml` - (Whatever you gave the name of the layout) and check it again.

Comment: I added the code of the custom_view so u can see it

Comment: In custom listview, what you will design in the custom layout it will show in the main layout as a row.

Comment: yea I added the "android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in the custom_xml but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all these parameters in `<ConstraintLayout ...>` element are unnecessary:

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
```

They don't have any meaning. Those parameters are used on elements *inside* ConstraintLayout, not on Layout itself. Layout fills all available space (in case of activity, it is whole screen), whatever layout are you using. Generally, just use `match_parent/wrap_content` in `width/height`, and that's it.

Secondly, based on your screen I cannot say where the ViewPager is located. It looks like ViewPager itself is left aligned in whole activity, but I am not sure. If it is, than it is the reason why everything squashed to left side. You can activate Developer Options on your device, then find and activate option Show Layout Bounds, than you will see on your screen borders of all rendered elements and see if this is the case.

Additionally, your item does not have very proper layout. If you want to chain these three elements, all of them should have all four `layout_constraintXxx_toYyyOf` elements. You can find it described [here](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb). I am not sure that this is the cause of your problem, but certainly is something that might cause the issue. Also, unless you really need to use ConstraintLayout, I would advise to use here LinearLayout, or even just plain text/button with drawableStart and drawableEnd set. It is [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) on TextView class (Button is just a subclass of a TextView.)

Comment: The reason I have those parameters its because that constraint layout is inside another constraint which I didn't show since its a long xml, the viewpager is attached on the left side to the planet looking icon, on the right side to the button and on the top to the tabLayout.

Comment: Ah, okay... I have a feeling that you have made those views more complicated then they should be. I am not sure what is the view pager part on your screenshots, so that I can help you how to simplify it.

Comment: Added a picture in blueprint view of the parent layout with the viewpager, maybe you understand it better. I'm trying to center the custom_item inside a fragment which is inside that viewpager (the big rectangle in the blueprint view).

Comment: Hierarchically under ViewPager you have Fragment > ListView > ListView item > item's content, if I understood correctly. So, make ViewPager take horizontally as much space as possible, and then starting from Fragment to the bottom of hierarchy, make everything as narrow as possible, and set Fragment to be horizontally centered inside of view pager, if it is possible.

Comment: Slightly alternative approach would be to make Fragment also as wide as possible, and then on ListView level to do narrowing and horizontally centering. You can even go further and make ListView horiuzontally match_parent, and then content inside of list view item center align horizontally. Either way, you need to take all available space from the top level in hierarchy, and then at some level go as narrow as possible and center align that level.

Comment: Ok I fixed it with Shadahat comment, it took me a while to understand what he was saying. All I had to do was center the custom_item on its own custom_layout so I wrapped it on a linear layout and added center gravity and that was it. I edited his comment with how I fixed it but he haven't reviewed the edit. Thanks for helping

Comment: That is basically what I was telling :) You were missing somewhere in view hierarchy to center everything :)